# Using 'quota' for disk limits

Tags: disk, user-space

I installed [quota](http://linux.die.net/man/1/quota) using apt-get and followed some of the tutorials online.

I ran `sudo edquota username` which opened [nano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) and gave a chart for me to edit. What does the chart mean when it says soft, hard, etc.?

Is there a proper tutorial for quota on Ubuntu? What's the official website for quota?

Or is there another option for setting user disk limits?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a quick and easy tutorial for setting up disk quotas.  It also defines the differences of hard quota and soft quota.  It also shows how to set a grace period.

It is generic and should work under any version of Ubuntu.

Hope this helps!

[disk quota 5 steps](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/disk-quota/)

Comment: It's adviced to quote some of the relevant parts into your answer in case the article goes down.

Comment: Again, whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.