# How to set disk quota for multiple users within a single disk partition

Tags: server, partitioning, disk, quota

I have a single disk partition (say `/shared`) shared by multiple users. It has a single file system (ext3). I want to put home directories for each of the user here and set their disk limit to 5 GB. Thus `/share/home/user1` could have up to 5 GB and `/share/home/user2` have could have up to 5 GB.

What is the command line way (not GUI) to do this?

Comment: Take a look at this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/7044/using-quota-for-disk-limits Basically you need edquota util from quota package (apt-get install quota) to set up disk quote for users

Answer (score 1):

Answered by @Flint:

Take a look at [Using 'quota' for disk limits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7044/using-quota-for-disk-limits)

Basically you need `edquota` util from `quota` package (`apt-get install quota`) to set up disk quote for users.

Please mark as answered.

Comment: An answer should not be a simple link to another solution. Kindly rehash the original solution, put your insights and helpful hints, and thus produce a good answer which further enriches this sight.