# How much disk space is assigned to a new user in ubuntu?

Tags: adduser, useradd

If I create a new user `test1` using the `adduser/useradd` command, how much space does Ubuntu assign to the `test1` user?

What happens when I have 10 users on my system? Do all of them use the same amount of space?

Comment: By default any user can use up all the disk space available in total. This can be changed.

Comment: It means the /home/test1 grows with time?

Comment: I just created a new user using adduser command. It has created a home folder /home/test1  on my system. Now how much space this new user can use on my system?

Answer (score 5):

The minimum amount of space a user needs is:

```
fab-root@fab-ux-predator:/home/test_user
$ du --human .
36K .
```

The maximum amount of space a user can take is 95% of the entire partition [unless you set disk quotas](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7044/using-quota-for-disk-limits) per user or [unless you change the number of reserved blocks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19504/reasonable-size-for-filesystem-reserved-blocks-for-non-os-disks) to allow them to take more or less than 95%...

Comment: It means a single user in default setting can take up 90% of space. Unless I use quotas to assign specific amount for each user.

Comment: I verified that in the meantime and it's 95%, but yes: you need to define disk quotas.  As you're an occasional user on this site, don't forget to accept (and upvote???  **:-)**) if this solved your problem.

Comment: @Rinzwind Changed "Hard drive" to "partition" (I was using OP's terminology).   **:-)** The standard for `mkfs` is 5% reserved blocks for root as going beyond 95% will cause fragmentation. [Read the blurb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19504/reasonable-size-for-filesystem-reserved-blocks-for-non-os-disks) I'm linking to.  **;-)**

Comment: +1. I did already upvote your answer due to the link about disk quotas :-)

Answer (score 3):

The standard setup is that the size of the directory `/home/test1` is only limited by the size of the partition and its file system and the space allowed for standard users to access.

5% of the space in an `ext4` file system is reserved for the system and for running tasks with elevated permissions.

See `man mkfs.ext4`,

> ```
> -m reserved-blocks-percentage
> ```
>
> Specify  the  percentage  of  the  filesystem  blocks reserved for the super-user.  This avoids fragmentation, and allows
>   root-owned daemons, such as syslogd(8), to continue  to function 
>   correctly  after  non-privileged  processes  are prevented from
>   writing to the filesystem.  The default percentage is 5%.

Comment: Sorry, I started writing it before your answer was published; ninja'd by @Fabby ;-)

Comment: Happens [a lot around here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634370/why-does-apt-get-not-require-restarts-where-the-update-manager-does/634375#634375) @sudodus  I was just a teensy bit faster...

Comment: +1 because you said "partition" and I said "hard drive"...