# Workstation - How to check space left?

Tags: disk-usage

I am using a workstation that is shared with others. I dont know what that means but I think some space is shared. How can I know how much space I have for myself? I ran `df -h` below

[image]

Comment: Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question next time and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code). However, your `df` output does not help here. You don’t seem to have a separate home partition, so you should be able to utilize all the space of `/` (maybe also `/data`), unless there is some form of [quota](https://linux.die.net/man/1/quota) applied.

Comment: Looks like there is 210GB available on /dev/sda2 and 2TB available on /dev/sdb1.
However, I can not see a way to tell if the users have a quota set. If quota is installed and you have admin access you can check your user or group to see any limits set.
`$edquota username` (for users)
`$edquota -g groupname` (for groups)

[quota-ubuntu-debian](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-quota-ubuntu-debian)

Answer (score 0):

You need super user access to determine a users quota utilizing `quota`. you can determine is it's installed with the command `which quota` and if not and you DO have super user access you can install it with `sudo apt install quota`

If it is installed and you don't have super user (sudo) access you can check your group quota with `quota -g` which if no filesystems are setup with quotas will respond by returning the prompt. you can also issue the command `edquota -g` or edquota -u username` (where username is your username) which if no quota is setup should return:

`No filesystems with quota detected.`

For information on how quotas are setup see [Using 'quota' for disk limits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7044/using-quota-for-disk-limits)

If no quotas have been established `df -h` should provide everything you need to know with the Avail column providing available space.

In the case of a quota you can calculate your available space by subtracting your disk usage `du` from your quota.

Sources:

`man quota`