# GParted shrinks the partition and then reput it to its original size

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I'm working on a live ubuntu, I have a non system disk with just one partition sda (not mounted) taking all the disk. I want to shrink the partition to create a second one after. Gparted does the job, says it's OK, but when I close the resizing window after it has finished, I still have my partition taking all the disk, only the filesystem is shrunk, so I can't create a second partition. Gparted show an exclamation point on the partition.  When I open the information it says the filesystem is not taking all the space, I can correct it with check. If I do it i return to my starting point.

Any idea please ?

Edit, here is gparted after the resizing :

[image]

Comment: You need to show us a `gparted` screenshot.

Comment: Do you have a backup of the data on this disk? It would be wise to make one if not. Your disk appears to be mounted at /mnt/2ttd and from what you have shown us there is no partition. Just a filesystem on a device. Ideally delete everything, create the partitions and restore the data from backup

Comment: Thank you PonJar, I guess this is the good way to go, I noticed my partition was named sda and that should be the name of the device.

Comment: See [Is there any benefit to partitoning hdd data-only disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209553/is-there-any-benefit-to-partioning-hdd-data-only-disk) for other reasons for partitioning a disk.

Comment: Yes, in my case I think I was too sure I didn't need several partitions in the future, I don't remember what happened in my head at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again PonJar, that was it. I had a file system without partition (no partition table) in my disk, I did wrong things when I installed Ubuntu on my new PC. Saving datas elsewhere, creating partition table, creating partitions, was the good way to go.